# Return two values from views exposed filter - filtered value and a default value

Tags: views

Is it possible to return two values when user chooses a value from a defined list? The values I wish to return are the value that a user chose AND a default value if it exists.

I have a taxonomy list of values (example: 10%, 20%, 25%, 100%, Any%). This list is exposed to the user as a dropdown filter on form.

I have a content type with an entity reference field referring to these values. Some or all of these values may be referenced in this field.

If the user chooses, for example 10% then the returned results should show products that have 10% set but I also want it to return Any%, if that is referenced in the product. So Any% should be shown alongside the product always, if it is referenced on that product.

Is this possible within views UI or do I need a query alter?

Default view before a choice is made

| Product 1 | Percent Available |
| --- | --- |
|  | 10% |
|  | 20% |
|  | 30% |
|  | 45% |
|  | Any% |

Example 1: User has chosen 10% from exposed filter:

| Product 1 | Percent Available |
| --- | --- |
|  | 10% |
|  | Any% |

Example 2: User has chosen Any% from exposed filter:

| Product 1 | Percent Available |
| --- | --- |
|  | Any% |

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by splitting it up into two filters:

The exposed one, as you described it above. Then add 2nd, non-exposed filter on the same field, and the field value must be `Any%`. Then, in the views UI, create a filter group, move both filters in there, and set the group condition to `OR`.